# Good sources about advanced scraping?

Tags: javascript

I build many scraping based on node + puppeteer + PostgreSQL as data storage and queue.

Everything works great, but I want to develop myself, my next goal to scraping data from + 100 000 000 pages (I have my proxy server with squid). When I can find sources to learn advanced scraping data, optimize performance, etc?

What would you recommend to me?

Comment: What do you mean by advanced scraping? How is it different than what you do already

Comment: More scalable, better performance than default puppeteer etc.

Comment: This is not related to machine learning per se